# rails: how to tell controller / action to return json format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is the code generated by scaffold

```
      # DELETE /swimming/classtimes/1
      # DELETE /swimming/classtimes/1.json
      def destroy
        @swimming_classtime = Swimming::Classtime.find(params[:id])
        @swimming_classtime.destroy

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to swimming_classtimes_url }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end

  end
```

This html code will send a request for html format

```
<a href="/swimming/classtimes/42" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a>
```

or rails code

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', swimming_classschedule, :method =>:delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }%>
```

How to tell action to return json format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify that the generated `<a>` tag markup returns JSON. If you're using the Rails `link_to` helper, you can pass the `data-type` attribute like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', swimming_classschedule_path, :method =>:delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, "data-type" => "json" %>
```

If you're looking for pure HTML markup, something like this will work:

```
<a href="/swimming/classtimes/42" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow" data-type="json">Destroy</a>
```

Alternatively, you could simply point your `href` to retrieve JSON explicitly:

```
<a href="/swimming/classtimes/42.json" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a>
```

As an FYI, the second code snippet is basically the interpolation of the first one.

Comment: Thanks, what about pure html way to send json request ?